# Why index could be convert to multikey automatically in MonogoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Given one empty collection `testdoc` with index as below

```
`db.testdoc.createIndex({"ratings.score": 1});`
```

Then insert one document `db.testdoc.insert({_id: 3, ratings: {score: 23}})`

For query `db.testdoc.find({"ratings.score": 23}).explain()` and the winning plan is

```
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "ratings.score" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "ratings.score_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "ratings.score" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "ratings.score" : [
                        "[23.0, 23.0]"
                    ]
```

The `isMultiKey` is false.

However, after insert this document `db.testdoc.insert({_id: 1,item: "ABC",ratings: [ { score: 2, by: "mn" }, { score: 9, by: "anon" } ]})`

The winning plan of above query is

```
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "ratings.score" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "ratings.score_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "ratings.score" : [
                        "ratings"
                    ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "ratings.score" : [
                        "[23.0, 23.0]"
                    ]
                }
```

The `isMultiKey` is true now.

Why the index could be changed to isMultiKey when document structure is changed?

MongoDB version: 4.2.5

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you create an index on an existing array field MongoDB will create multi-key index i.e; multiple index keys for each element in an array. Let's say in your case even if you've created a normal [single field index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/) initially & later on if you add a new document with the indexed field as an array then MongoDB will automatically convert existing index into multi-key index, as an array is being inserted for that particular field.

**Ref :** [multikey-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)